# getting the gettext behavior using the Po File Loader in the translation provider in Silex

Tags: symfony, translation, silex

I'm using the translation provider and the PoFileLoader in Silex and everything works super great.

```
$app['translator'] = $app->share($app->extend('translator', function($translator, $app) {

    $translator->addLoader('po', new PoFileLoader());
    $translator->addResource('po', __DIR__.'/resources/translations/de.po', 'de');
}
```

The only problem that I have is how it treats strings that doesn't have translation yet. I want them to be ignored and use the source instead of an empty string. Like the way gettext function treats the po files.

Is there any option for that or should I override the PoFileLoader class?

Answer (score 0):

> The only problem that I have is how it treats strings that doesn't have translation yet. I want them to be ignored and use the source instead of an empty string. Like the way gettext function treats the po files.

This is something the translator does, not the file loader. If there is no translation found in the message catalogue, the translator will just replace the parameters and return the source.

See also the [source](https://github.com/symfony/Translation/blob/master/MessageCatalogue.php#L121-132):

```
public function get($id, $domain = 'messages')
{
    // ... all the loading logic

    // if everything failed, just return the source
    return $id;
}
```

This method is called in the [`Translator#trans`](https://github.com/symfony/Translation/blob/master/Translator.php#L188) method.

Comment: Well I'm using the trans() function and I know that. I saw that behavior in the xliff files before. But in my po file for strings that don't have translation I have a line like msgstr "" and the translator thinks the empty string is the translation. But native gettext ignore this.